# Solve 0x8007001f error on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I installed `bash` Ubuntu on Windows 10 100% and create just a username. After installation, I ran bash but I got error `0x8007001f` on command prompt.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Would you consider posting a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after installing and moving the 'rootfs' to another partition and creating a symbolic link to it to save space on root SSD Partition,

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: Uninstalling (lxrun /uninstall), removing the Symbolic links and reinstalling to the default location %userprofile%\appdata\local\lxss (lxrun /install)  works fine.  Would love to be able to move it though.